# Creating extra column with OneToOne annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an user object and I need to load group object along with the user object.

I have written for that the following code.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "User_info")
public class UserDao {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int userId;

   @Column(name="first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name="groupId")
   private int groupId;
        
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   private GroupMaster groupMaster;
    
   //setters and getters
}
```

and `GroupMaster`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_master")
public class GroupMaster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int groupId;

    @Column(name="groupName")
    private String groupName;
    
    //Setters and getters
}
```

Here the `group_master` is the master table and it has `groupId` and `groupname`.

I will give the `groupId` in `user_info` table based on that value I need to get the `groupMaster` object. But the problem here  is hibernate is creating

```sql
CREATE TABLE group_master
(
    group_id integer NOT NULL,
    group_name character varying(255),
    user_user_id integer NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT group_master_pkey PRIMARY KEY (group_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fkjxrn8rglp972s1pqfh5tsb6cu FOREIGN KEY (user_user_id)
       REFERENCES user_info (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );

ALTER TABLE group_master OWNER TO XYZ;
```

I don't know why it creates `user_user_id` column. I don't have any use with this `user_user_id` column. The relation should be with `groupId`.  How can I fix it.

Comment: don't call your User "UserDao". A DAO is something different. Treat JPA Entities like regular classes modelling your business domain.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher yeah naming convention missed, I will correct it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define the @OneToOne relationship in both sides so you need to add the @OneToOne annotation to the GroupMaster too, to make it in the properly way you should do it like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User_info")
public class UserDao {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    GroupMaster group;

 //setters and getters
}
```

then the GroupMaster Entity should be like this :

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "group_master")
    public class GroupMaster {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int groupId;
        @Column(name="groupName")
        private String groupName;
       
        @OneToOne
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        UserDao user;

        //Setters and getters
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate groupId-column or the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn Annotation
Change your UserDao to:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "User_info")
public class UserDao {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private GroupMaster groupMaster;

 //setters and getters
}
```

Comment: I am getting `error Null value was assigned to a property 
[class Model.UserDao.groupId]
of primitive type setter of Model.UserDao.groupId;
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property 
[class com.kcs.util.bulkmailer.Model.UserDao.groupId] of primitive type setter of Model.UserDao.groupId`

Comment: But the values are not coming to the `groupMaster`